# Replace string in all columns of data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe in R, which contains some coverage information of sequenced samples.
The columns has a lot of text data. I would like to extract just the coverage numbers from it

here is the code

```
df <- data.frame(sampleA = c("There is a 91.24% of reference with a coverageData >= 1X", "There is a 90.89% of reference with a coverageData >= 2X", "There is a 90.46% of reference with a coverageData >= 3X"),
        sampleB = c("There is a 91.22% of reference with a coverageData >= 1X", "There is a 90.99% of reference with a coverageData >= 2X", "There is a 90.77% of reference with a coverageData >= 3X")
        )
```

This is what the data frame looks like

```
                                                   sampleA
1 There is a 91.24% of reference with a coverageData >= 1X
2 There is a 90.89% of reference with a coverageData >= 2X
3 There is a 90.46% of reference with a coverageData >= 3X
                                                   sampleB
1 There is a 91.22% of reference with a coverageData >= 1X
2 There is a 90.99% of reference with a coverageData >= 2X
3 There is a 90.77% of reference with a coverageData >= 3X
```

I would like to get the output as

```
  sampleA sampleB
1 91.24  91.22
2 90.89  90.99
3 90.46  90.77
```

I see that `mutate_all` can be used. But not sure about the syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `readr::parse_number()` inside `dplyr::across()`:

```r
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), parse_number))
#>   sampleA sampleB
#> 1   91.24   91.22
#> 2   90.89   90.99
#> 3   90.46   90.77
```

Data from OP

```r
df <- data.frame(sampleA = c("There is a 91.24% of reference with a coverageData >= 1X", "There is a 90.89% of reference with a coverageData >= 2X", "There is a 90.46% of reference with a coverageData >= 3X"),
                 sampleB = c("There is a 91.22% of reference with a coverageData >= 1X", "There is a 90.99% of reference with a coverageData >= 2X", "There is a 90.77% of reference with a coverageData >= 3X")
)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Targeting a percentage value among other numbers, using `sub` and `%` as marker.

```
data.frame(sapply(df, function(x) 
  as.numeric(sub(".* ", "", sub("%.*", "", x)))))
  sampleA sampleB
1   91.24   91.22
2   90.89   90.99
3   90.46   90.77
```